# ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P002, instance 8 ORA-01722: invalid number

Tags: oracle, etl, integrator

ODI-1228: Task Merge rows-IKM Oracle Merge-Load HVN_S_INVOICE_1 fails on the target connection ADWC_HVNBIIT. Caused By: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-12801: error signaled in parallel query server P002, instance 8 ORA-01722: invalid number

Hi , i am not able to resolve this error in oracle 12 c studio integrator . What should i do to resolve this error

Need step to resolve the error

Comment: HI Anurag,
As it says : Invalid Number :
Are you sure you are not trying to convert 
non-numeric string to a numeric value ?

Comment: Hi Tushar there is no column mentioned here where can I check if the query is converting non-numeric string to a numeric value and the inserting file has around 80k data

Comment: If you don't have a way to handle the bad row / data error within the ETL then you're likely going to have to identify which columns *should* be numbers and then manually review your source data to find the bad row or rows.